# Botframework send proactive message then string not empty

Tags: python, email, botframework, chatbot, microsoft-teams

I have a problem sending proactive messages using the Bot Framework with Python.
First what I need is to get the message body from Outlook, and then the bot must send that as a message to all the chats where it was added.

To do that, first I created a new file and called it **Email.py**.

To read every incoming message body I simply used `while true:` and `time.sleep()`

Here is my code example:

```py
import imaplib, email, getpass
from email import policy
import json
import time

imap_host = 'outlook.office365.com'
imap_user = 'xx@xx.com'

# init imap connection
mail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(imap_host, 993)
rc, resp = mail.login(imap_user, 'xxxxxx')
while True:
    # select only unread messages from inbox
    mail.select('Inbox')
    status, data = mail.search(None, '(UNSEEN)')

   if not data[0].split():
         time.sleep(120) 
    # Bot message variable
    Message_for_bot = ''
    # for each e-mail messages
    for num in data[0].split():
        # get a single message and parse it by policy.SMTP (RFC compliant)
        status, data = mail.fetch(num, '(RFC822)')
        email_msg = data[0][1]
        email_msg = email.message_from_bytes(email_msg, policy=policy.SMTP)

    # print only message parts that contain text data
        for part in email_msg.walk():
            if part.get_content_type() == "text/plain":
                for line in part.get_content().splitlines():
                   Message_for_bot += '\n' + line             
        print(Message_for_bot)
```

After I successfully created a program to read and print all incoming messages, I tried to build my bot. I found a [proactive message bot on the Internet](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/samples/python/16.proactive-messages) and used it as an example.

First I thought to just run this file with `os` in the background, but then my bot wasn't running. So then I tried adding an `async` function in the bot file but it didn't work. My bot just ignores that function. (Then I found the async functions in activity_handler.py, but I didn't find any that could help me.)

Then I tried adding an `on_message_activity` function and thought maybe it will start working if I call the bot like "@bot hi" for example in Teams. For that idea I must always run the while cycle and never stop the bot, but then I just get a message, and if there's a new incoming message then the bot doesn't write it anymore, and it's not a solution because if the bot is used for multiple chats then it simply doesn't work this way.

Then I try include my code on `on_members_added_activity` it seems working on azure test in web chat perfectly, but in teams after 1-2 messages stopping to work.
my code

```
async def on_members_added_activity(
        self, members_added: [ChannelAccount], turn_context: TurnContext
    ):
    
        imap_host = 'outlook.office365.com'
        imap_user = 'xxxxxx@xxxxxx.com'

        # init imap connection
        mail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(imap_host, 993)
        rc, resp = mail.login(imap_user, 'xxxxxx')
        while True:
            # select only unread messages from inbox
            mail.select('Inbox')
            status, data = mail.search(None, '(UNSEEN)')

            if not data[0].split():
                time.sleep(5) 
            # Bot message variable
            Message_for_bot = ''
            # for each e-mail messages
            for num in data[0].split():
                # get a single message and parse it by policy.SMTP (RFC compliant)
                status, data = mail.fetch(num, '(RFC822)')
                email_msg = data[0][1]
                email_msg = email.message_from_bytes(email_msg, policy=policy.SMTP)

            # print only message parts that contain text data
                for part in email_msg.walk():
                 if part.get_content_type() == "text/plain":
                    for line in part.get_content().splitlines():
                        Message_for_bot += '\n' + line       
                                
                await turn_context.send_activity(f"{Message_for_bot}")
        for member in members_added:
            if member.id != turn_context.activity.recipient.id:
                await turn_context.send_activity(
                    "bot starting work..."
                )
```

So maybe it's possible to send a message to wherever the bot is added (it needs to get this information somehow, maybe it's kept in the bot memory) whenever `Message_for_bot` is not empty.

All help will be appreciated.

Comment: Just normal case proactive message is  working ?

Comment: @Kalakutas - Do you have a question? (Since there are multiple other people in this thread, you will need to @ mention me if you want me to see your reply.)

Comment: @Vinoth Rajendran then i test on azure web chat, first need write, when restart and then working proactive message.

Comment: @KyleDelaney yes i do, How send message with bot, then my Message_for_bot  string not empty.

Comment: @Kalakutas - I'm sorry but it's very difficult to understand what you're saying. I've edited your question for readability, so can you please have a look at my edits to see if the question is still saying what you mean for it to say? It sounds like you're saying your bot sends proactive messages based on emails, but then you say you're using `on_message_activity` which is unrelated to proactive messages. Were you able to run the proactive messaging sample by following the instructions in the readme?

Comment: @KyleDelaney I give just example, I know on ```on_message_activity```, will start work only if you type for bot. But then I try add my code on it or ```on_members_added_activity```, its working a bit, but then stops, idk why because, bot seems running, don't give any error,  In ```azure test in web chat ``` its working perfectly

Comment: @Kalakutas - it sounds like you'll need to debug the bot to see what's happening. Have you read the debugging docs? https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/bot-service/bot-service-debug-channel-ngrok

Comment: @Kalakutas, You can create a subscription api to notify in teams when a new mail is received. Please go through this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/subscription-post-subscriptions?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=javascript#example) and [sample](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/aspnetcore-webhooks-sample#creating-the-subscription).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we have discussed some logic has to change

1. Move your code out of the on_members_added_activity function
2. Use Proactive concept to send the message

-Vinoth